# Adding a Server to Domain

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have a server dedicated to recording for one of our programs. Its particular program is supposed be a program we can use to remote to that computer and pull recordings or monitor traffic from radios. From what I was told from the person who did this before me is that how this supposed to work is that the program remotes to that machine and then that machine connects to a VNIC. For some reason it jumped off of the network and will no connect back. I continually get this error:

DNS was successfully queried for the service location (SRV) resource record used to locate an Active Directory Domain Controller for domain :
The query was for the SRV record for _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.

The following AD DCs were identified by the query:

```
<netbiosname>.<domain name>
```

Common causes of this error include:
- Host (A) records that map the name of the AD DCs to its IP addresses are missing or contain incorrect addresses.
- Active Directory Domain Controllers registered in DNS are not connected to the network or are not running.

I checked for the record but it looks like its there.

Comment: What do you get when you ping _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.'''domain.com'''? Usually this is a DNS issue.

Comment: There's a lot of extraneous details here...is your issue that you cannot add this server back to the domain?

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured out on my own just in case anybody sees this! My problem was group policy, server went down, and windows firewall issue!